# MySQL query to convert normalized data into single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a query to format content from normalized tables into a single row.

What I would like is something like this with a single row for each contact:

```
Name               Mobile            Office          Home
---------------    -----------       ----------      ----------
Fred Flintstone    123-456-7890      234-567-8901    789-012-3456  
Barney Rubble      456-789-0123                      678-901-2345
Wilma Flintstone   567-890-1234                      789-012-3456
```

What I am getting from my latest query is this, with multiple rows per contact:

```
Name               Phone           Phone_Type
---------------    ------------    -----------
Fred Flintstone    123-456-7890    Mobile
Fred Flintstone    234-567-8901    Office
Fred Flintstone    789-012-3456    Home
Barney Rubble      456-789-0123    Mobile
Barney Rubble      678-901-2345    Home
Wilma Flintstone   567-890-1234    Mobile
Wilma Flintstone   789-012-3456    Home
```

Here are the tables involved (simplified):

```
contacts
----------
contact_id
name

link_contact_phonenumbers
-------------------------
contact_id
phone_number_id

phone_numbers
-------------
phone_number_id
phone_number
type_id

ref_phone_types
---------------
type_id
name
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    cn.name as Name,
    concat( left(ph.phone_number,3) , "-" , mid(ph.phone_number,4,3) , "-", right(ph.phone_number,4)) as Phone,
    pt.name as Phone_Type
FROM
    contacts cn
    LEFT JOIN link_contact_phonenumbers lp ON lp.contact_id = cn.contact_id
    LEFT JOIN phone_numbers ph ON ph.phone_number_id = lp.phone_number_id
    LEFT JOIN ref_phone_types pt ON pt.type_id = ph.type_id
```

I looked at using GROUP_CONCAT() function, but that pulls all the content into a single column.  I need them to go into their own columns.

I've been looking into subqueries combined with IF() but haven't figured it out yet.

Is there a way to do this in pure SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution for others that will find this in the future:

```
SELECT 
    cn.name as Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.type_id = '1' THEN ph.phone_number ELSE NULL END) as Mobile,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.type_id = '2' THEN ph.phone_number ELSE NULL END) as Office,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.type_id = '3' THEN ph.phone_number ELSE NULL END) as Home      
FROM
    contacts cn
    LEFT JOIN link_contact_phonenumbers lp ON lp.contact_id = cn.contact_id
    LEFT JOIN phone_numbers ph ON ph.phone_number_id = lp.phone_number_id
    LEFT JOIN ref_phone_types pt ON pt.type_id = ph.type_id
GROUP BY cn.contact_id
```

Found this solution here: [How to Denormalize a Normalized Table Using SQL](http://www.transio.com/content/how-denormalize-normalized-table-using-sql)

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can accomplish what you are looking for with a few joins:

```
Select a.name, c.phone_number, d.phone_number, e.phone_number from contacts a 
    left join link_contact_phonenumbers b on a.contact_id = b.contact_id 
    left join phone_numbers c on b.phone_number_id = c.phone_number_id and c.type_id = "whatever id is mobile"
    left join phone_numbers d on b.phone_number_id = d.phone_number_id and d.type_id = "whatever id is office"
    left join phone_numbers e on b.phone_number_id = e.phone_number_id and e.type_id = "whatever id is home"
```

I do not know if this is the most efficient way, I also don't have a database to test with right now so it might be off, but it should point you in the right direction. Also might have to group by a.name in case the first join adds multiple rows.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon.  This solution creates the different columns but there are still multiple rows per contact. Each row for the different type of phone number. Anyway to bring them together?

Comment: did you try to group by a.name, i added it to the answer below the code but it might have been after you read it.

Comment: I did miss it in your comment, sorry.  I added the group by a.name (or a.contact_id) and it did limit it to one row per contact.  However, it only had one of the phone numbers and not the others. So it didn't merge the content of the rows into one, it just showed one of them.

Comment: I found a solution here: [link](http://www.transio.com/content/how-denormalize-normalized-table-using-sql). It uses `MAX` and `CASE` to pull the non-NULL data to a single line.